# Jena TDB in Python?

Tags: python, storage, jena

Is it possible to run a [Jena TDB database](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/tdb/) from a Python app to store a large amount of RDF data? What would be a native alternative in Python?

Comment: Could you use Jython to run the python code?

Comment: Yes I can run anything I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative is to run the python code under [Jython](http://www.jython.org/) not the normal C based Python run time.

Jython converts python code to the JVM language. It cannot therefore call python extensions that use C but it can call all Java classes including the Jena TDB and all pure python modules.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative is to use a SPARQL endpoint such as Apache Jena's Fuseki and just use an HTTP client from Python or any other language.

To read more about Fuseki, look here:

- http://incubator.apache.org/jena/documentation/serving_data/

Answer (score 4):

http://code.google.com/p/python-graphite/ A Python package that make it possible to use Jena in Python